# How do you call a delegate exported via MEF with late binding?

Tags: dynamic, mef

What I'm trying to do is for this to work:

```
GetMethod(Key key)(...some arguments...)
```

The "...some arguments..." varies between each call of GetMethod, including in number of parameters, so there is no specific Action<...> that I can use.

Now the GetMethod looks through the argument list to find a match within a list of Tuple and returns the second argument of the Tuple, which is the dynamic. This list was created using MEF by

```
<some CompositionContainer>.GetExports(new ImportDefinition(a => true, "...", ImportCardinality.ZeroOrMore, true, false))
            .Select(e => (Tuple<Key, dynamic>)Tuple.Create((Key)e.Metadata["Key"], e.Value))
            .ToList();
```

Now, it seems that the second item in the typle isn't actually an Action of the appropriate type, but rather a ExportedDelegate. Is there any way to make so that the second item is actually a correct Action, so that GetMethod(...)(...) actually does work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [ExportedDelegate.CreateDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.exporteddelegate.createdelegate%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).  Pass in the type of delegate you want (ie Action).  MEF uses ExportedDelegate so that you aren't restricted to using Action<> and Func<> delegates, but can use any delegate type with a matching signature.

You also probably need to specify the contract name in the constraint you pass to the ImportDefinition constructor, instead of just passing `a => true`.

Comment: So to clarify, my scenario (using GetMethod(...)(...)) won't ever work, as I would need to know the exact delegate I'm looking for? I can't just tell the ExportedDelegate to be called with the arguments that it is passed?

Comment: No, at some point you need to know what the delegate type needs to be.

Comment: Alright. Not the answer I was hoping for, but nothing much can be done about it.